# Confirmationbox inside a php whileloop

Tags: javascript, php

I have a site where I can update my Database. In the same page I also have a tabel with the most importent information in the database. This tabel is generated by a php while loop, and at the end of each row I have a Edit-button and a Delete-button. But I want to have a confirmation to the deletebutton. But I dont knopw how..

This is my code:

```
mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass") or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("kalender") or die(mysql_error());
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM event where datum > now() ORDER BY `pub` DESC LIMIT 0, 40") or die(mysql_error());
echo '<table>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<th>Nr</th> <th>V.</th> <th>Tid</th><th>Dag</th><th>Datum</th><th>Ändra</th><th>Ta bort</th>';
echo '</tr><tr>';
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data))
{
$eventTime=$info['datum'];
$tid= strtotime($eventTime);

echo '<td width="20px">' .$info['id'] . '</td>';
echo '<td width="20px">' .$info['vecka'] . '</td>';
echo '<td width="40px">' .date("H:i", $tid) . '</td>';
echo '<td width="40px">'.$info['dag'] . '</td>';
echo '<td width="50px">' .date("j M", $tid) . '</td>';
echo '<td width="70px"><a href="http://kalend.mizgalski.se/update.php?id=' .$info['id'] . '"><button id="checkoutbutton" type="button"><Edit</button></a></td>';
echo '<td width="70px"><a href="http://kalend.mizgalski.se/delete?id=' .$info['id'] . '"><button id="checkoutbutton" type="button">Delete</button></a></td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Please help me!

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**pink box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try this.

**In PHP Script:**
Update this in while loop

```
    ...
    ...
    $tempId = $info['id'];
    echo "<td width='70px'><a href='javascript:;' onClick='go_edit($tempId);'><input type='button' value='Edit'/></a></td>";
    echo "<td width='70px'><a href='javascript:;' onClick='go_del($tempId);'><input type='button' value='Delete'/></a></td>";
    ...
    ...
```

**In Javascript:**
Add these functions in under php script

```
<script>
function go_edit(id) {
   window.location.href = "http://kalend.mizgalski.se/update.php?id="+id;
}
function go_del(id) {

 var choice = confirm('Are you sure want to delete?');  
 if(choice) {
    window.location.href = "http://kalend.mizgalski.se/delete?id="+id;
 }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do confirmation using javascript on the client side before sending data to the server